# Jquery U.S Map multiple selection from label

Tags: jquery

i am using jquery U.S Maps

i have labels on it in which i have to select the multiple states from single label

i have done multiple selection on states click giving them id . i gave ids to label but both are different to how can i link labels to multiple states

this is the array where labels are generating

var neStates = ['new', 'NH', 'MA', 'RI', 'CT', 'NJ', 'DE', 'MD', 'DC'];

and added the id to these

// Create the hit areas

```
    this.labelHitAreas[state] = R.rect(x, y, shapeWidth, shapeHeight, shapeRadius).attr({
      "fill": "#ff0000",
      "stroke-width": 0, 
      "opacity" : 0.0, 
      'cursor': 'pointer'
    });
    this.labelHitAreas[state].node.dataState = state;
    this.labelShapes[state].node.setAttribute("id",state);
      //  console.log(this.labelHitAreas[state]);
```

but this is selecting only one state per label.

Comment: *...select the multiple states from single label* is there only one label for all 50 states? *i gave ids to label but both are different to how can i link labels to multiple states* Labels need `for=idOfState` and states are `id=idOfState` Need HTML and probably CSS. Is this map a SVG?

Comment: yes its SVG map

Comment: No HTML/CSS on a map project? Good luck.